# action="#{sessionHandler.login}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'sessionHandler' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, mojarra, propertynotfoundexception

I have a test JSF Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http:/java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id="testButton" value="test" action="#{sessionHandler.login}"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The commandButton calls a backing bean called SessionHandler:

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionHandler {
    @Inject
    private SessionEJB session = new SessionEJB();
    public SessionHandler(){}
    public String login(){
        return "video.xhtml";
    }
}
```

The problem is when I click the button, its not finding the backing bean method. I'm getting this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /test.xhtml @10,94 action="#{sessionHandler.login}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'sessionHandler' resolved to null

root cause

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /test.xhtml @10,94 action="#{sessionHandler.login}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'sessionHandler' resolved to null

root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /test.xhtml @10,94 action="#{sessionHandler.login}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'sessionHandler' resolved to null
```

Why is it not finding my backing bean?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The exception clearly tells that it could not find the `sessionHandler`.

Comment: Okay, then why is it not finding the backing bean?

Comment: Too many probable causes (generally all boiling down to a starter mistake). Start with excluding the ones listed in "Related" column on the right hand side and/or [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException%20Target%20Unreachable%20identifier%20resolved%20to%20null). Or, better, throw away that low quality tutorial/resource you're currently using to learn the stuff and restart with a decent one. Usually a real book is the best.

Comment: I was using "Beginning Java EE 7" by Antonio Goncalves (A real book). I still can't figure out what mistake I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem, which was not visible with the original code I posted, so, I apologize for that. Despite the error stating that sessionHandler was resolved to null, it was in fact the EJB which I was referencing that could not be located. This was because I was importing the EJB Jar into the build path rather than putting it into the WEB-INF/lib folder. Although, I believe the appropriate way is to create an Enterprise Application Project and reference both the EJB Jar project and the Web project. So, my problem had nothing to do with my code but had to do with how I referenced a project. I hope this helps anyone faced with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're mixing JSF beans and CDI beans, which you cannot. Just replace the import `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` with `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` and you're all on CDI.

Also a SessionScoped bean should be passivation capable and therefore implement `Serializable`.

Comment: Unfortunately, after changing that import, I still am faced with the same exception.

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: I am using glassfish 4.0.1, JSF 2.2, and Eclipse Keplar

Comment: I have made the backing bean Serializable by importing java.io.Serializable. Unfortunately, my problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

In Java EE, there are two ways to declare beans for JSF. Either with the old managed bean facility:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped
public class SessionBean {}
```

or with CDI (now the recommended way)

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class SessionBean {}
```

To enable CDI, you also need a [beans.xml in the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv001.htm#CACDCFDE).

Comment: According to the link you sent, it says you don't need a beans.xml deployment descriptor if you annotate a class with a scope type. Which in my case I did use @SessionScoped. Though, I tried including the beans.xml file in the link and still no luck.